# Eloquent Laravel show Trying to get property 'code' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 model created like below:

`Employee.php`

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function grades(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class);
    }
}
```

and also

`Grade.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Grade extends Model
{
    public function employee(){
        return $this->hasMany(Employee::class);
    }
}
```

when I try to show code ane name of Grade in tinker like below

```
$a=App\Employee::find(15);<br>
$a->grades->code
```

it gives me error :

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'code' of non-object in Psy Shell code on line 1*

`table employees`:

[image: employees]

`table grades`:

[image: grades]

Comment: Can you provide the migrations being used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `grades()` method in the `Employee` model to `grade()`.

Eloquent uses the method name to determine the database column to use for the relationship. It would have also worked if you changed the column name to `grades_id` or if you optionally defined the column on the relationship like this:

```php
public function grades() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Grade::class, 'grade_id');
}
```

Comment: wow, I didn't know it works, is it about plural thing?
could you please explain?

Comment: @Goon Plural method names (i.e. `grades`) are for has many relationships. Singular method names (i.e. `grade`) are for belongs to relationships where you’re only expecting a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Please add `with` and try :

```
$a = App\Employee::with('grades')->find(15);
```

Comment: `App\Employee {#2950
     id: 15,
     code: "19610202",
     name: "Adzull",
     grade_id: 11,
     position: "a Position",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     grades: null,
   }`